# Where can I find System.Memory documentation?

Tags: c#, .net, system.memory

Where can I find the actual docs for things like Span<T> and Memory<T>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the docs for Memory and Span on github by going [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/memory.md) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/span.md).